# Wrap date ordinal with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have some HTML structured as such:

```
<span class="time">Monday, December 24th</span>
<span class="time">Tuesday, December 25th</span>
<span class="time">Monday, December 31st</span>
```

I cannot change the HTML output. What I would like is to wrap the date ordinal in a tag so I can style it with CSS, so it would look like:

```
<span class="time">Monday, December 24<sup>th</sup></span>
<span class="time">Tuesday, December 25<sup>th</sup></span>
<span class="time">Monday, December 31<sup>st</sup></span>
```

I cannot just find/replace in a string, because, for example, if someone put "Thursday, April 11th", the word "Thursday" contains "th".  So I have to parse each string, find the numbers, and then see if a date ordinal follows them in order to wrap it in a `<sup></sup>` tag.

Something like this that finds the number, but how can I wrap the next two letters, rather than the number?

```
$('span.time').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, v) {
      return v.replace(/(\d)/g, '<sup>$1</sup>');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8yao4rLu/

Any ideas?

Comment: seems to be the last 2 characters in your sample, or the characters from on the last number?

Comment: It could be, but I would love a solution that searches out by finding the number rather than that, in case someone ever put "Monday the 21st of April" or something like that

Comment: You're 90% of the way there with your prose explanation: use a regex that looks for a number `[0-9]`, followed by `(th|st|rd)` and replace that token with `<sup>$1</sup>`.

Comment: Honestly, I think parsing it via momentjs and figuring out the datetime format would be less fragile than attempting to find 2 characters after a number.

Comment: You really don't need jQuery for this: `document.querySelectorAll('span.time').forEach( node => node.innerHTML = node.textContent.replace(...))`. And it doesn't really have anything to do with dates. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: you just need two "capture groups" which are bounded by parenthesis `()` in the regex. You then specify what to do with each group you find.

In this case, you just re-print `$1` (the number) and pop the `$2` into a tag.

```js
$('span.time').each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, v) {
      return v.replace(/([0-9]+)(th|st|rd|nd)/g, '$1<sup>$2</sup>');
    });
});
```

```html
<span class="time">Monday, December 23rd</span> <br/>
<span class="time">Tuesday, December 24th</span> <br/>
<span class="time">Monday, December 31st</span> <br/>
<span class="time">Monday, December 2nd</span> <br/>
<span class="time">Monday, 1st of December</span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is [a visualization](https://regexper.com/#%2F([0-9]%2B)(th%7Cst%7Crd%7Cnd)%2F) of the regular expression above:

[image: regexper railroad diagram of regex]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming consistent formatting from server, you can do a string `replace()` on last 2 characters.

Using `html(function)` simplifies looping and accessing the exisitng content

```js
$('.time').html(function(_, existing){
    return existing.trim().replace(/(..$)/, '<sup>$1</sup>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="time">Monday, December 24th</span>
<span class="time">Tuesday, December 25th</span>
<span class="time">Monday, December 31st</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This will definitely work, but is there a way to do it by identifying the number in case the string ever changed and it was something like "Monday the 21st of April"?

Comment: Modify the regex for the suffixes only instead

Comment: @RCNeil just in case, I mean I get the class is saying its a time, but you may want to actually completely parse the entire date time.  What happens if it's `<span class="time">Monday, December 24th, 2008</span>`  You have to really be careful when using regex.